# Automatically add a new sender address (subaddress) to GMail?

Tags: gmail, userscripts

I use [subaddressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Subaddressing) constantly in my GMail account, creating a new address several times per day. However, the user experience when doing this leaves a lot to desire:

1. Either I have to manually create a new address which is a slow and cumbersome multistep process (rather than just editing the sender field) using the web ui or
2. use Thunderbird where I can edit the from-field but then I can't use the GMail SMTP-server¹ = problems with SPF, DKIM etc.

Are there better solutions?

I imagine a solution where you execute some kind of script (bookmarklet perhaps?) that alllows you to enter the desired from-address and the script then performs all the steps required to create a new address automatically, opens a new message with the specified from-address and, after the message is sent, removes the address it just created.

¹ If I use the GMail SMTP-server, the from-address is reverted to the default address.